# How can I assign materials symmetrically?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have a character that I want to assign materials to symmetrically, but it doesn't have a Mirror modifier or anything like that.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Maybe duplicate, assign a Mirror modifier to the copy?

Comment: It's not working, another way?

Comment: Oh ok, I've tried with a Suzanne's head and it doesn't work, I'm not sure why, so maybe you need to give a Mirror modifier to the original object then? Also I see that there is a plugin that allows you to symmetrize UVs if you don't want them to overlap + if you have a symmetrical image texture: https://blendermarket.com/products/symmetrize-uv-util

Comment: Thank you so much!